# AWS Managed AD SSL Certifcates export

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to explore AD integration and was able to succesfully complete the setup as described in [AWS blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-enable-ldaps-for-your-aws-microsoft-ad-directory/), and verified that SSL connection is working fine from "Management box".

Based on my understanding, ldp.exe from Management box is working fine because management box is joined to this AD and certificates are propagated properly.

I have use case where another linux box (which can't be joined to AD) but should use LDAPS over SSL to do some user search. For this to work, I need to export SSL and install it on Linux box. I couldn't quite figure out how to find and export certificates in this example? Are those certificates are available on RootCA (or) SubordinateCA and how to export them? appreciate any help.

Comment: Based on that example "Step 2: Setup S3 Bucket to Store Certificate Revocation Lists (CRLs) and Certificates" there's a s3 bucket with the certs.

Comment: @lloyd Ok, so these are the certs I can import at client vms too? This is what I am confused.

Comment: I haven't carried out the steps. If you've completed the setup, you should have a set of artifacts from the setup. What are they please?

Comment: [powershell get-ldapcert](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/89qze7/getldapcert_get_ldap_endpoint_public_certificate/) might be worth a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you generated the SSL cert in AWS via Amazon Certificate Services (ACS). Although ACS won't allow you to export the private key from ACS, you shouldn't need it. All you need to do is import the public certificate into the certificate trust store that your Linux box is using when it connects to the AD server. I can't tell you how to do that (not sure what the application is), but you should be able to extract the public cert using openssl. You'll point openssl to the ad server, and have it output the public cert.

I'm pretty sure this is the openssl command line that would do that:
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect activedirectory.yourdomain.com:636

Comment: No, I didn't generate certificates using ACS.As described in the linked example, used a RootCA server and subordinateCA server.

Comment: OK, well you still need to import the public cert into your application cert trust store. the openssl command above will export it for you. Then you'll need to import it.

Comment: I got it working. openssl is interesting command to test this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
You can download the certificate from the ldaps end point and install it as follows.

Install openldap client
sudo yum install -y openldap-clients
•   Download and Add Server Certificate to the openldap cert path
        openssl s_client -connect <LDAPSURL>:636 -showcerts </dev/null 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -outform PEM > server.crt
•   Configure LDAP Details
        Vi /etc/openldap/ldap.conf
        BASE dc=corp,dc=example,dc=com
        URI ldaps://corp.example.com
        TLS_CACERT /etc/openldap/certs/server.crt
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).